# How to make Perl use different handles for pipe input and keyboard input?

Tags: perl, input, pipe

I have a Perl script processing a pipe.  At some point, I would like the script to pause and ask for user keyboard input.  `my $input = <STDIN>;` does not work.  It just reads next line from the pipe.  How can I make Perl use different handles for pipe input and keyboard input?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are on a Unix platform, you can open a filehandle to `/dev/tty` (or use [`IO::Pty`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Pty)). 
A good example of working with tty is in "Testing Whether a Program Is Running Interactively" example here: http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_perl/userinterfaces.html

You should also consider doing password IO via [`Term::ReadKey`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadKey) (described in [perlfaq8](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How-do-I-ask-the-user-for-a-password?)) - I think it may be tied to TTY instead of STDIO but am not sure. If it isn't, use the TTY+Term::ReadKey solution listed at the end of [this SO answer by brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021482/how-do-i-read-a-single-character-from-stdin-using-perl-on-windows/2021550#2021550).

Here's an example.

[It's not the best style (doesn't use 3-arg form of `open`, nor uses lexical filehandles)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-lexical-filehandles-a-perl-best-practice) but it should work.

```
use autodie; # Yay! No "or die '' "
use Term::ReadKey;
open(TTYOUT, ">/dev/tty");
print TTYOUT "Password?: ";
close(TTYOUT);
open(TTY, "</dev/tty");
ReadMode('noecho', *TTY);
$password = ReadLine(0, *TTY);
```

Comment: @Arkady - you are welcome. Please feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it (that'll gain you 2 rep points too) as well as to up-vote the answer (up-arrow next to it)

Comment: `ReadMode` also takes the terminal as second arguments: `ReadMode('noecho', *TTY);`. I submitted this as an edit, so it should be in the original post soon.