# PHP CLI: How to read from keyboard STDIN when using pipe?

Tags: php, scripting, command-line-interface

I am making a script that accepts data input both via:

1. filename (it opens a .txt file for reading)
2. pipe (reading via "php://stdin")

In both cases, I need to get controls from keyboard, stdin;

1. When opening the file **not** using pipe(stdin) I can read the keyboard from

```
./myscript.php --file filename.txt
```

then

```
<?php

$DATA = file_get_contents("filename.txt");
// etc loop
$input = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); // works
stream_set_blocking($input, false);
$key = fgetc($input); // get input from keyboard
echo $key;

?>
```

2. But when using pipe, this does not work, example:

```
cat filename.txt | ./myscript.php
```

then

```
<?php

$DATA = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
// etc loop
$input = fopen("php://stdin", "r"); // does not works
stream_set_blocking($input, false);
$key = fgetc($input); // get input from keyboard
echo $key;

?>
```

Why can't I read from keyboard in the second case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it reading directly from `/dev/tty`

```
<?php

$DATA = file_get_contents("php://stdin");
// etc loop
$input = fopen("/dev/tty", "r"); // this works, as stdin == pipe
stream_set_blocking($input, false);
$key = fgetc($input); // get input from keyboard
echo $key;

?>
```

I found the answer here:

[How to make Perl use different handles for pipe input and keyboard input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854971/how-to-make-perl-use-different-handles-for-pipe-input-and-keyboard-input)

Also:

[Can I prompt for user input after reading piped input on STDIN in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484431/can-i-prompt-for-user-input-after-reading-piped-input-on-stdin-in-perl)